# Relative class display

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list of divs on a page that all contain 3 divs with the same class, basically the below code is repeated 10 times with a different background image -

```
<div class="tab floatLeft" id="l_e_male">
    <div class="number">
        7
    </div>
    <div class="freeze">
        <img src="images/tabs/pin.png" width="31" class="navSwitch" height="33" alt="Pins" />
    </div>
    <div class="edit">
        <img src="images/tabs/edit.png" width="31" class="navSwitch" height="33" />
    </div>
    <div class="scale">
    </div>
</div>
```

The scale div is hidden (it will be a dynamic .net scale) and I only want it to appear when the edit button is clicked.  But I want to write a dynamic script that will do this for each tab without having to reference the id  Can anyone please suggest the best method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("div.edit").click(function(){
  $(this).next("div.scale").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div.edit img.navSwitch').click(function() {
   // do stuff
   $(this).next('div.scale').show();
});
```

Comment: cheers that looks interesting - but how would I script it to only show the scale div within this tab and not the others?  Could I use 'this'?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work...

```
$(".edit img").click(function(){
     $(this).next().show();
});
```